# limit view result to only commented nodes

Tags: 7, views, comments

I created a view that gets the logged in user posts, But I need to alter that view a little bit to only show the posts that has a comment by a different user "not the OP".

Do I have to create a template and add PHP to it? or this can be done with views?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to code something here with powerful Views module.

1. First, add relationship *“Comment: Comments of the node”* to current View.
2. Then in *“Query settings”* check *“Distinct”* option. Now you have list of nodes which have comments.
3. Add contextual filter *“Comment: Author uid”*, set default value to *“User ID from logged in user”* and don't forget to check option *“Exclude”* in *MORE* fieldset.
   [image]
   [image]

Note that this solution works only for current logged in user.

Comment: I dont think "Then in \“Query settings\” check \“Distinct\” option. Now you have list of nodes which have comments. "   is correct. Distinct will just remove duplicate results.

Comment: I managed to get only the commented nodes by adding a filter "content: comment count". and gave it a value "equal or greater than" 1

Comment: All the steps are interrelated. To set the third step correctly you have to configure (1) and (2).